# R combine two data frames by NA

Tags: r, join, merge, dataframe

I have a data frame (DF) and like to combine two columns in the first of them by replacing the NAs in the first column with the values in the second. Here is an example DF:

```
structure(list(A = structure(c(3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), .Label = c("five", "four", "one", "three", "two"), class = "factor"), 
B = structure(c(4L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 6L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("eight", 
"four", "nine", "one", "seven", "six", "ten"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", 
"B"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see the DF contains the numbers from one to ten in two columns.

**I want the NAs in column A to be be replaced by the values in column B. But only the NAs of A!**

I tried:

```
X$A[is.na(X$A)] <- X$B[is.na(X$A)]
```

But this gives me an invalid factor level error warning.

Solutions I found mostly deal with merge() or paste(), but I think that's not going to help here. Your suggestions are welcome, as always :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it necessary to have factors instead of characters ?

Comment: No it's not. Should have tested for that. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use factors. This should work:

```
X$A <- as.character(X$A)
X$B <- as.character(X$B)
X$A[is.na(X$A)] <- X$B[is.na(X$A)]
```

If you want to avoid `data.frame()` function converting everything to factors before you have modified your data, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` option. For example: `data.frame(apply(X, 2, as.character), stringsAsFactors = F)`.

Comment: Great. It was obvious after reading your solution … and testing for factors will now be part of my error searching routine :) Thanks.

Comment: It's confusing, I know. I had similar problems when I started. If you want to avoid `data.frame` function converting everything to factors before you have modified your data, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` option. For example: `data.frame(apply(X, 2, as.character), stringsAsFactors = F)`